# Simple Calculator that isn't working

Tags: php, html, forms, post

I want to develop an ez breezy calculator to upload to a page on my site.  I have written both the HTML and PHP code to the best of my understanding but still fail to produce an answer to my screen.  After I click the "button", I get redirected to a blank screen with no code.  When I try it in my site, it takes me back to my home page...every time!  Below is all the code...I need help!

```
<?php
    $a=$_POST["'a'"];
    $b=$_POST["'b'"];
    $c=0;    
?> 
<meta charset="utf-8">
<html>

<head>
<title>Proposal Sheet Calculator</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="/Merchant Calc 1.php">
<h1>How Much Money Are You Losing?</h1>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<h2>How many clients walk out your business each month when finding out they don't have the cash or credit to pay?<br/>
    <input type="text" name="'a'"><br/></h2>
<h2>What is your average ticket price?<br/>
    <input type="text" name="'b'"><br/></h2>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<h2><input name="calc" type="Submit" value="Show me the numbers" /></h2>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<br/>
<p>
<?php
$a = $_POST[‘a’];
$b = $_POST[‘b’];
$c=$a*$b
// should output $a*$b
if(isset($_POST[‘submit’])){
echo "$a * $b";
}

more?<br/>
<input type="text" name="'Y/N'"><br/>
<input name="calc" type="Submit" />
if(isset($_POST[‘submit’]))<br/>
</p>
?>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't even get to the "more?" input...it dumps me out before that so I have not done anything below the "more?" lines.  And the crazy output of the last if statement...WebMatrix shows no errors.?.?.?.?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please share the code of Merchant Calc 1.php file...

Comment: its good, if you dont use spaces for file names.

Comment: make your form action=""

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
?>
<html>

<head>
<title>Proposal Sheet Calculator</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="">
<h1>How Much MONEY Are You Losing?</h1>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<h2>How many clients walk out your BUSINESS each month when finding out they don't have the cash or credit to pay?<br/>
    <input type="text" name="a"><br/></h2>
<h2>What is your average ticket price?<br/>
    <input type="text" name="b"><br/></h2>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<h2><input name="calc" type="Submit" value="Show me the numbers" /></h2>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<br/>
<p>
<?php
$a = $_POST["a"];
$b = $_POST["b"];
$c=$a*$b;
// should output $a*$b
if(isset($_POST["calc"])){
echo $c;
}

?><br/>
<input type="text" name="'Y/N'"><br/>
<input name="calc" type="Submit" />
<br/>
</p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have few syntax errors, fix them it will work.

Firstly, add semicolon `;` in this line

```
$c=$a*$b;
        ^
```

Next, you are enclosing multiplication operation inside double quotes, so multiplication will now work, it will be considered as string. so remove double quotes.

```
echo "$a * $b";// will echo number * number
```

change to

```
echo $a * $b;// will echo multiplied value.
```

Next remove `action` to your form. I mean make action as `action=""`

Next access either usnf single quotes or double quotes not both.

```
$a=$_POST["'a'"];
```

this should be

```
$a=$_POST["a"]; or 
$a=$_POST['a'];
```

and also

```
<input type="text" name="'Y/N'"><br/>
```

this also

```
<input type="text" name="Y/N"><br/> or
<input type="text" name='Y/N'><br/>
```

Comment: Ok, changes made but still not printing anything to the screen. still "refreshing" the screen once I press the first submit ("Show me the numbers" submit button).  When I click to submit, the screen changes back to the original home page of my site...what have I missed???

Comment: no.  my site is built with Joomla! 3.4 and I am thinking that the issue might be with them......or is it???  How do I get my code to stop and wait for the calculation to show?  If I can't make this work, I'm going to lose this customer that wants to see it.

Comment: When I click the "Show me the numbers" button (a submit button), it resets the screen and shows a fresh form.  There is no output to the screen...and if there is...it happens in a blink before the reset.

Comment: <html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="">
<h1>How Much MONEY Are You Losing?</h1>
<h2>How many clients walk out your business without the cash or credit to pay?</h2><input type="text" name="a"></h2>
<h2>Average ticket price?<input type="text" name="b"></h2>
<h2>Net Profit Margin?</h2><input type="text" name="d">
<h2><input name="calc" type="Submit" value="Show me the numbers" /></h2>
<?php
$a = $_POST["a"];
$b = $_POST["b"];
echo $a * $b;
if(isset($_POST["calc"])){
echo $c;
}
<input type="text" name="Y/N"><br/>
<input name="calc" type="Submit" />
?>
</form>
</body>
</html>

Comment: I had to edit out some of the "routine" codes to make it fit (like <p>nbsp;</p> and <br/>'s etc)

Comment: IF...if it is displaying the value, then something is happening after it is displayed.  When run (on multiple browsers), as soon as I click to submit, it refreshes the screen to show a blank/fresh HTML form.  I have made some kind of progress to where it's not redirecting to the main page

Comment: please show the code. you can edit in question itself.

Comment: the code is the same as the corrected version above.  I have installed XAMPP on my laptop and am figuring out how to use it.  When the code is placed on my Joomla powered site...as soon as you click the 'submit' button...everything is wiped clean...doesn't show an answer but refreshes the page.  I've look at many other calculators and their work stays to be viewed...why not mine?